# How to change the value of a variable in one class from another? Java

Tags: java, variables, command-line-arguments, instance-variables

I am having issues getting variables I have declared in one class to update from another class. Is this even possible in Java?

Here is the portion of the class that I want the values to change in.

```
public class DrawMaze {
   // Width of border in pixels
   public static int borderwidth = 40;

   // Size of maze cell in pixels
   public static int cellsize = 30;

   // Time to sleep after a move (in milliseconds)
   // Change to default to 50. 1000 gives time to observe the program.
   public static int sleep time = 1000;
}
```

And here is a portion of my second class where the values of `cellsize`, `borderwidth`, and `sleeptime` are to be changed using command line arguments.

```
public class MazeSolver {
    // Get the cell size, border width, and/or the sleep time if available 
   try{
       if (args.length >= 2){
           DrawMaze.cellsize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           if (!(DrawMaze.cellsize >= 10)){
              System.out.println("Cellsize must be an integer greater than or equal to 10."); 
           }
       }
       if (args.length >= 3){
           DrawMaze.borderwidth = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
           if (!(DrawMaze.borderwidth >= 5)){
                  System.out.println("Borderwidth must be an integer greater than or equal to 5."); 
           }
       }
       if (args.length == 4){
           DrawMaze.sleeptime = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
           if (!(DrawMaze.sleeptime >= 0) && !(DrawMaze.sleeptime <= 10000)){
                  System.out.println("sleeptime must be an integer in the range of 0 to 10,000."); 
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with your code is that `args.length = 4` should be `args.length == 4`. If it's not working how you expect, add more information to clarify the problem and make answering it easier.

Comment: Just to note in case it's relevant, the variable for args[0] is not shown, but it exist in my code as just a string. The other arguments [1], [2], and [3] are all integers accepted for the variables in the shown code.

Comment: this is really bad practice, what you're doing is functional programming with global state and all of that is against OOP. Consider usnig instantiated classes and objects with state that are shared. Further more you can use Design patterns like Factories or Singleton to make sure you always get same object if that is required by your application.

Comment: Thanks, JavaNut13, I'll try to clarify a bit more.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. My teacher gave me partially completed code and gave instructions to make it functional.